# iPython with different env (using anaconda)

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I have just created a new env with python 3.5 using anaconda (called it python35). My root env points to python 2.7.11. I cant seem to launch ipython with this new env, here is what I did

```
1. in conda prompt, activate required env: activate python35
2. confirm the version: python --version
3. launch ipython: ipython notebook
4. open a notebook and do: import sys; print (sys.version)
```

Step #2, returns 3.5 but step #4 always gives me 2.7.11, its like ipython is picking up python version from root env. How do I fix this. Thanks for any help!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983822/how-to-activate-ipython-notebook-and-qt-console-with-python-3-4-in-anaconda-2-0?rq=1) question is related but I have already done what it suggests.

Comment: Did you install ipython in `python35`?

Comment: Oops, no I have not. Would you please know how to do that.

Comment: Try `python35/bin/python ipython notebook`?

Comment: When in `python35` env, try `conda install ipython-notebook` in command prompt

Comment: @AndreySobolev You sir are a genius. That fixed it. If you dont mind posting it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Here you are :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK, different environments in anaconda (and in venv as well) are activated by *prepending* env path to `$PATH` environment variable. It means, that if some file (eg, `ipython`) is not found in env path (the first entry of `$PATH`), the system searches for it in consequent entries of `$PATH` and finds it in root environment (that stays in `$PATH`). To fix the behavior, you need to install its own copy of `ipython` to anaconda env:

1. In command prompt, activate the environment: `source activate python35` (or simply `activate python35`, depending on the OS)
2. While in environment, issue the command `conda install ipython-notebook`

Comment: I more question please - do I need to install all other things as well. Because currently it does not even recognize numpy. Throws "ImportError: No module named 'numpy'"

Comment: Yes, you need to install all packages you need in the same manner (as even the codebase might be different for different Python versions)

Comment: And actually that is the essence of virtualenv - to provide the user with completely isolated (that is, independent from root) Python environment

Comment: Is there a way to install all common packages in a new environment, I mean the default installation comes up numpy, scipy etc. is there a single command to install all such in packages in new environment as well.

Comment: You can write a requirements.txt file, and then do `conda install --file requirements.txt`

Answer (score 6):

An addition to Andrey Sobolev solution,you should switch to `conda install ipython` for higher python3.x version and log out the environment by `Ctrl+D` or `conda deactivate` then activate again

Answer (score 0):

I could confirm the solution above (basically install notebook in active environment) in my case. Two updates from my side:

1. Since Anaconda 4.4 (?) ipython notebook is now [jupyter notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook).  So I had to install jupyter instead.  I guess, deactivate and activate was required afterwards to get the path variables in notebook updated -> checked by python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" or corresponding command in notebook.
2. If you aren't using a isolated [anaconda environment](https://docs.anaconda.com/ae-notebooks/user-guide/adv-tasks/work-with-environments), you may eventual calling the notebook package from your native OS-Python installation, instead the desired from Anaconda. Similarly, I had trouble with cmake or cxx, when I try to compile in Anaconda Environment - the diffent root folder might found in linux bash with e.g "which jupyter"